# loadLibrary fails with error findLibray returned null when using .so from other source

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a libother_team.so file from other team, I have added this .so directly in my project under path libs/armeabi-v7a/

When i try to load this library it fails with below error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load other_team from loader    
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.testapp-1.apk,
libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-1]: findLibrary returned null
```

I am blocked on this issue and any help regarding the same highly appreciated.

Comment: With adb shell or terminal list the content of /data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-1

Comment: Since you say that building it yourself works, but the version provided by someone else fails, there's a good chance that they are using the wrong toolchain or settings.  You can compare the files with the ndk's readelf or objdump.  Also, this error message seems different than I would expect.  What command are you using to explicitly load the native library, and what does running that cause to appear in logcat? (you should definitely see something about success or failure).

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the .so library into the correct path?
The correct paths are:

- /libs/armeabi
- /libs/armeabi-v7a
- /libs/mips
- /libs/x86

based on the device architecture.

Also, be sure that the function you are trying to call is correctly defined into C code (and, obviously, that the Java native method correctly corresponds to the C function). Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615) for more info.

Comment: Yes, i have the .so in right path <myproject>\libs\armeabi-v7a\other_team.so but still get the above error, to validate the same, i have added all the source code inside my \jni folder build the .so then it is working fine. But having only .so without any source for the same in \libs\armeabi-v7a\other_team.so FAILS !!

Comment: Juggernaut93, Are you sure these are the correct paths?  I believe the project folder is usually "libs" with an "s", while the install on the device automatically ends up in "lib" without.

Answer (score 0):

To have the library installed to `/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-1` it must follow the naming convention: **lib**whatever**.so**. You will use `System.load("whatever")` in your static constructor to load it. You can rename the 3rd party file as you wish. Make sure that your new name is unique enough, because if Android device has same name in `/system/lib`, then the system library will be loaded by Java.